# Why does Prefix Incrementor Overload return Type& instead of Type?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, prefix, postfix-operator

Just started doing operator overloads and my teacher didn't go too in depth into them so I was wondering why the return type is different for Prefix/Postfix increment/decrement. When I see the prefix overloads the return type is written as Type&, but the return type for the postfix is written as Type. I made the prefix without the & and the functions both ran properly. Does the return type affect anything or is it just another way to distinguish prefix from postfix?

Answer (score 2):

The reason is to allow chaining:

```
++ ++ ++ i;
```

To allow `i` to triple increment, `++` must return the reference and take the reference. If it returns a temporary copy, the second `++` would increment ... the temporary copy (in fact, a temporary copy won't bind a `&`, so it will not even compile).

Comment: @Slava - No, a user defined operator involves a function call that adds proper sequence points to the expression. This is *very* different from `i++ + ++ i` for an `int` variable.

Comment: Actually that brings interesting question if chained prefix UB for builtin. Asked it here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35464793/why-chained-prefix-increment-decrement-for-builtin-type-is-not-ub-for-c

Comment: `++ ++ ++ i` is the same as `op++(op++(op++(i)))`: the order of evaluation is unique. 

Thats different from `i++ + ++i`, alias `op+(op++(i,0), op++(i))` where the two `op+` parameters can be evaluated in whatever order, modifying `i` with different histories, thus giving an UB.

Answer (score 1):

To add to Emilio's answer postfix incrementing creates a temporary variable and sets that to 1 plus the variable you want to increment where as prefix incrementing increments the actual variable which can have a performance boost in certain cases.

Answer (score 0):

Main reason is to follow semantics for builtin types in C++ where prefix increment/decrement returns lvalue and postfix one returns rvalue. Details can be found [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_incdec)