# Why chained prefix increment/decrement for builtin type is not UB for C++?

Tags: c++, prefix-operator

In cpprefernce.com [example](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_incdec) for prefix increment there is such code:

```
int n1 = 1;
...
int n3 = ++ ++n1;
```

Why chained increment in this case does not lead to UB? Is rule for at most once modified not violated in this case?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In C++11 and later, UB occurs when there are two writes or a write and a read that are unsequenced and access the same memory location. But `++x` is equivalent to `x+=1`, so `++ ++n1` is equivalent to `(n1+=1)+=1`, and here the reads and writes happen in a strict sequence because of the properties of assignment and compound assignment operators: first `n1` is read, then one plus the original value is written, then the resulting value is read again, then one plus that value is written back.

In C++03, this *was* UB, because of the old rule you allude to: there is no sequence point between the two modifications. But in C++11 there are no longer any sequence points; instead there is the "sequenced before" partial order.

Comment: It became way too complicated

Answer (score 2):

See [Brian's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35464886/1621391) answer for simpler terms, .

It's legal cause the C++ standard says so, emphasis are mine... Going by the C++14 draft

**5.3.2 Increment and decrement [expr.pre.incr]**

> The operand of prefix ++ is modified by adding 1, or set to true if it
>   is bool (this use is deprecated). The operand shall be a modifiable
>   lvalue. The type of the operand shall be an arithmetic type or a
>   pointer to a completely-defined object type. **The result is the
>   updated operand; it is an lvalue**, and it is a bit-field if the
>   operand is a bit-field. If x is not of type bool, the expression ++x
>   is equivalent to x+=1

So, this is perfectly legal

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    int x =8;
    int y = ++ ++ ++ ++ ++ ++ ++ ++ x;
    cout << x << " " << y;

}
```

Output

```
16 16
```

**1.9 Program execution [intro.execution]**

> **15**...If a side effect on a scalar object is unsequenced relative to either
>   another side effect on the **same scalar object** or a value computation
>   using the value of the **same scalar object**, the behavior is undefined. ...

And it's attached example:

```
void f(int, int);
void g(int i, int* v) {
i = v[i++]; // the behavior is undefined
i = 7, i++, i++; // i becomes 9
i = i++ + 1; // the behavior is undefined
i = i + 1; // the value of i is incremented
f(i = -1, i = -1); // the behavior is undefined
}
```

Comment: "See Brian's answer for the actual answer"... sorry, I couldn't resist.

Comment: I did not ask if that is syntactically correct, I asked if that leads to UB, which is completely different.

Comment: I quoted the standard with respect to the operators themselves, "...the result is an lvalue..." basically has one part of the answer there...

Comment: Well, I've since updated it. I didn't see Brian's answer earlier, that was why I modified my answer to acknowledge his